# Use EF6 with ASP.NET Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am working a new project - and I want to do it using the latest .NET Core.

Reading through the documentation, I came across the comparison between Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6.x Comparison. [Here](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/features.html#side-by-side-comparison)

Some of the features that I require like: `Spatial Data Type` is NOT supported by EF Core. So I CAN'T use it, because Spatial Data Type is required in the Project.

Going through the documentation again, I came across this link on How to use EF 6.x with .NET Core: [Here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html)

In the article it mentions ([Here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html#prerequisites)):

> Before you start, make sure that you compile against full .NET
>   Framework in your project.json as Entity Framework 6 does not support
>   .NET Core. If you need cross platform features you will need to
>   upgrade to Entity Framework Core.

I don't really need my project to be cross platform.

#### The article is not very clear on how to use EF6 with ASP.NET Core.

I created a new `ASP.NET Core Web Application`

then I installed EF6 using Nuget Package Manager, and got the following error

[image]

I went and removed the `netcoreapp1.0` from the frameworks in `project.json` and added `net46` as framework, which removed the error for EF, but now I am getting another error.

[image]

1. So how do I use EF6 with ASP.NET core?
2. When I use EF6 I have to remove all references to .NET Core, does
       this mean I am not using .NET Core? What are the disadvantages of this other than it can't run cross platform?

Comment: ASP.NET Core and .NET Core are different things.  When you create an ASP.NET Core project, you can choose whether to build against the .NET Framework or .NET Core.  You need to do the former to use EF6.  If you created a project that builds against .NET Core then you should toss it and create a new one that builds against the .NET Framework.  They are different options in the New Project dialogue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so I need to create an ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) project?

Comment: That's the one.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am going to be adding my Entities in a separate Class Library Project - Which type of Class Library project will I have to use? .NET Core class library or traditional Class Library targeting .NET Framework?

Comment: If you dont want cross platform application . Why cant you create a regular MVC applicaiton in 4.6 and EF 6.

Comment: @Eldho I want to use .NET 4.6 with latest Project structure

Answer (score 3):

To stop the second error you need to remove the following from the `dependencies` section of your `project.json`:

```
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "type": "platform"
}
```

For reference, the documentation for [referencing the full .NET Framework and Entity Framework 6 from an ASP.NET Core project](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/entity-framework-6.html#reference-full-framework-and-ef6-in-the-asp-net-core-project) has a full `project.json` example.

Removing references to .NET Core does not mean you are not using ASP.NET Core. You are only changing the target runtime platform that your ASP.NET Core project will execute on.

Using ASP.NET Core with the full .NET Framework, you get the benefits of the new project structure and unified story for building web UI and web APIs (e.g. unified `Controller` class), and you also gain access to the mature, fully-featured .NET Framework, enable use of dependencies and NuGet packages which haven't been ported to .NET Core, for example Entity Framework 6.